# Mysql database didn't working after overwritting installing wamp.

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using wamp server. I have made some project and there are some also databases.
I install new window and then i install wamp server in same drive where the wamp sever is.
After installing wamp my project file in "www" are present as pervious but in phpMyAdmin there is only database name is present when I open it there is no table. where the tables gone ???
I check the "wamp>mysql>data". Here the files are present of that tables but it does not show in the phpmyadmin.
I need these tables how can I recover it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you ,use the feature in windows called "restore previous versions" . 
Right click the Wamp folder click Restore previous versions and select the most recent date you know it was working,it maybe work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you did ...

Install new windows.
Install WampServer on new windows
Copy my old`\wamp\www` folder to the new install
Copy the subfolders in `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\data` to the new install

If this is correct, then dont forget to copy the contents of `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\data` as well. If you are using INNODB database the actual data lives in the ibdata1 file in that folder.